# What are differents between remember(todo.id) { randomTint() } and remember{ randomTint() }?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official sample [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/StateCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/codelabs/state/todo/TodoScreen.kt).

I find the app can run well when I replace `remember(todo.id) { randomTint() }` with  `remember{ randomTint() }` .

What are differents between  `remember(todo.id) { randomTint() }` and  `remember{ randomTint() }` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun TodoRow(
    todo: TodoItem,
    onItemClicked: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    iconAlpha: Float = remember(todo.id) { randomTint() }
) {


}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't point to the specific example.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the documentation for [remember](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function0))

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Function0) and https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function0)

Answer (score 0):

`remember` function is used to cache some state across recompositions. It can accept zero or more additional keys which are used to invalidate this cache. If any of the `key`s change, the lambda is reinvoked to calculate the new state value.

In you example `iconAlpha: Float = remember(todo.id) { randomTint() }` the `iconAlpha` value is remembered to be some `randomTint()`. Here `todo.id` has been passed as a key which means that whenever this `todo.id` will change the cached `iconAlpha` will get invalidated and the calculation block will be run again assigning a new value to `iconAlpha`.